# PHP/MYSQL: Running a complicated loop to retrieve data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

This is how it works..

There are list of users registered in the database.

As the users register in the database..

I want a create a 5-level of grading for them as more members registers..

It goes thus..

The first member will have **level 1** as soon as 30members are registered in the database..

It will move to ***level 2*** when 150more people registers.

It will move to ***level 3*** when 780more people registers.

It will move to ***level 4*** when 3900more people registers..

Then the last ***level 5***, it will move to level after 19530 people av registered..

**NOTE:** other members move to next level as well with intervals of 30 members registered but they Cant move unless the *1st member* has completed that current stage.

Please, I need help on how to go about. Spent days trying all types loops, Tried using array and pointers upto no avail.

1. **30members reg - 1st user(level one)** 
    60members reg - 2nd user(level one) 
    90members reg - 3rd user(level one) 
    120members reg - 4th user(level one)
   **150members reg** - 5th user(level one) **1st user(level two)** 
    180members reg - 6th user(level one) 
    210members reg - 7th user(level one) 
    240members reg - 9th user(level one) 
     270members reg - 10th user(level one) 
    300members reg - 11th user(level one) **2nd user(level two)** 
    330members reg - 12th user(level one) 
    360members reg - 13th user(level one) 
    390members reg - 14th user(level one) 
    420members reg - 15th user(level one)
   450members reg - 16th user(level one) **3rd user(level two)**
   480members reg - 17th user(level one) 
    510members reg - 18th user(level one) 
     540members reg - 19th user(level one) 
     570members reg - 20th user(level one) 
     600members reg - 21th user(level one) **4th user(level two)** 
     630members reg - 22nd user(level one) 
     660members reg - 23th user(level one) 
     690members reg - 24th user(level one) 
     720members reg - 25th user(level one)
     750members reg - 26th user(level one)
   **780members reg** - 27th user(level one) **1st user(level three)** 
     810members reg - 28th user(level one)

   and so on

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution will be make a column with name "count" in table and for every new user entered update the count of each users . from that count number you can tell the level i.e if count is more than 20000 than u can tell user is at level 5

Comment: additionally you can add one more column with name " level " and update the level at time of incrementing and updating count

Comment: i created a hidden column  named "id" as primary key and in auto increment.

Comment: all i want to do now is for message to pop up once the first user registered has 30 members registered underneath which indicates the first level. 150 members will elevate the first user to 2nd level

Comment: what you are trying to achieve with this illogical thing?